# Show Console in web

Tags: java, javascript, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm having a web application using PlayFramework. They way it works is I upload my files and in the background it runs a java application and process my files. Right now I'm doing this in a Thread and use .join() to wait for results. But I would like to show Console in my web so user can see the process and errors on the web while waiting. Is there any way I can show it ?

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar .//lib//xs.jar")
AROMAtracker tracker = new AROMAtracker(proc);
Thread aromaThread= new Thread(tracker);
aromaThread.start();
try {
    aromaThread.join();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
return ok();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `java.lang.Process.getOutputStream()` method to retrieve the output from your process. Sending it back to client can be achieved by using`play.mvc.WebSocket`. It will give real time processing impression. Optionally, you can wait until the thread is terminated and send output in one response.